# i want to convert my webcam video into rtmp format i use react as client and node js as server but facing issue I/ error

Tags: ffmpeg

```
const ffStreamYouTube = ffmpeg()
      .setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath)
      .input(dataStream)
      .inputFormat("bin")
      // .inputFPS(30)
      .videoFilters(`scale=${desiredWidth}:${desiredHeight}`)
      .videoCodec("libx264")
      .outputFormat("flv")
      .output("rtmp://localhost:1935/live")
      .on("end", () => {
        console.log("YouTube streaming finished");
      })
      .on("error", (err) => {
        console.error("Error:", err.message);
      });

    ffStreamYouTube.run();
```

This is the server-side code I got the data as binary

> ```
> FFmpeg Error: Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: rtmp://localhost:1935/live: I/O error
>
> at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\abhimanue\Desktop\Livenex\LiveNex\server\live-stream\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\processor.js:182:22)
> at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:512:28)
> at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:293:12) can anyone help me
> ```